# Best-effort OTP supervision

Tags: erlang, elixir, erlang-otp, erlang-supervisor

What I'd like to do is change my supervisor to make a best effort to keep children running, but give up if their crash rate exceeds the intensity. That way the remainder of the children keep running. This doesn't appear to be possible with the existing supervisor configurations, though, so it looks like my only option may be to implement my own supervisor so I can have it behave this way when it receives `EXIT`.

Is there a way to implement custom OTP supervisor behavior like this without writing your own supervisor?

Comment: Could you explain more about the specific use case? What you are describing sounds less like Supervisor not meeting your needs, and more like you may be trying to do something with supervision that has better alternatives. It sounds a lot like trying to do something during `init/1` that is prone to failure, causing processes to crash very quickly when being restarted.

Comment: So here I'm pulling service telemetry data for an internal monitoring tool from various sources. I use `simple_one_for_one` supervision and create these children dynamically based on the values in a config file that get passed when starting a child. The children are of a `gen_server` that periodically handles request based on a delayed message, and the only thing done in init is store the config as state and queue up the initial delayed message. This lets me pull in the data on a periodic schedule with each worker being independent of the others.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It sounds to me like what you want is an individual supervisor for each child, responsible for keeping it alive up to a limit, as you say, and as a layer above that have a single supervisor (one-for-one or simple-one-for-one) whose children are marked as temporary, so that when one of them gives up, the rest stay running.

Comment: Thanks! That sounds like exactly what I need!

Answer (score 4):

You can't "extend" `Supervisor` to add different supervision behaviour, but you don't have to start from scratch either. The `:supervisor` module itself is implemented on top of `:gen_server`, so I would consult the source code of `:supervisor` (which you can find [here](https://github.com/erlang/otp/blob/master/lib/stdlib/src/supervisor.erl)) if you do find yourself needing some kind of custom supervision behaviour; it will give you a base to build from to avoid some of the pitfalls which you are likely to encounter.

I can expand my answer about alternative solutions once I have a better idea of your use case. As I mentioned in my comment, it sounds to me that you are likely doing something during `init/1` of your processes which is prone to failure; `init/1` is not the place to handle those things, because if it becomes impossible to succeed at that action temporarily, you will almost certainly blow the max restart intensity of the supervisor.

For example, let's assume you have a process which talks to the database, and requires a database connection; you do not want to try and connect to the database during `init/1`. Rather you should acquire the connection post-init (perhaps on first-use, or by immediately sending a post-init message to the process using `Process.send_after(self(), :connect, 0)`), and if the connection fails, return something like `{:error, :database_unavailable}` to any callers while you attempt to re-establish the connection. Designing with this approach will allow your supervision tree to remain stable, and it instead pushes the decision on how to deal with failure down to the clients who likely have better information on how it impacts them (i.e., should they retry the operation, return an error to their caller, exit with an exception, etc.)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**director**](https://github.com/pouriya-jahanbakhsh/director) too, it's more flexible for solving this problem.